# how do i compare time with time which i set in textbox

Tags: c#

I wrote this code:

```
DateTime LateInTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dsAtt.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
int resultIn = DateTime.Compare(StfInTime, LateInTime);

if (resultIn > 0)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(LateInTime, AlwLateTime)<=0) // count for 15min
    {
        CLD += 1;
    }
    else if (DateTime.Compare(LateInTime, AlwLateTime1) <= 0) // count for 30min
    {
        CLD1 += 1;
    }
    else if (DateTime.Compare(LateInTime, AlwLateTime2) <= 0) // count for 60min
    {
        CLD2 += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        LateTime += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please  format your code more appropriate in future. (I've fixed this post for you.) Next, tell us the actual problem. You've presented us with code and a title, but that's all. Your "question" is unanswerable at the moment, as it's not a real question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I think you should have a look at [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) and then revisit your code

Comment: There is no question and no description what you are trying to achieve or what is the problem. Please give us more information about the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. It subtracts the two times to create a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) for the amount of time between them, then extracts the number of minutes that span represents:

```
DateTime LateInTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dsAtt.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
TimeSpan timeLateBy = LateInTime - StfInTime;
double minutesLateBy = timeLateBy.TotalMinutes;

if (minutesLateBy > 0)
{
    if (minutesLateBy <= 15)
        CLD += 1;
    else if (minutesLateBy <= 30)
        CLD1 += 1;
    else if (minutesLateBy <= 60)
        CLD2 += 1
    else
        LateTime += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works well but i want exact time difference, e.g: if my staff time is 8.30 and if i go at 8.45 that means i come late by 15min

Comment: If your staff time is 8:30 and you go (`LateInTime`?) at 8:45, then `minutesLateBy` _will be_ `15.0`; what do you want to _do_ with it?

Comment: i just want to calculate the late days